# Augmenting a generic, partial computed type with additional properties, changing optionality

Tags: typescript, types, typescript2.6

Our Angular 5 application previously shared a single type interface for retrieving *and* updating objects with the back-end. When updating, we would set unchanged fields to a magic value the back-end would later discard. This meant the UI had to send enormous objects for nothing (and magic values are rarely good practice).

We're fixing that by refactoring the update operation to send only changed fields, *along with a user-provided, optional change note*. This change note is only relevant in update operations and is never part of the primary interface.

Illustratively, we could get a `<Person>`:

```
export interface Person {
  id: number;
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
  email: string;
  division: Division;
}

type Division = "BUSINESS" | "PROD" | "SALES";
```

Now, when updating a `Person`'s `division`, the final payload looks like

```
{
  id: 12,
  division: "PROD",
  editNote: "Had enough of sales for the time being."
}
```

So, an update must contain an `id` (which exists in every interface and which is never optional), one or more additional fields from an interface, and an optional `editNote`.

I've gotten as far as creating a [mapped type partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html) and then extending the computed interface (it seems you cannot mix static and computed fields in a generic type):

```
export type Updater<T> = {
  [prop in keyof T]?: T[prop];
};

export interface PersonUpdater extends Updater<Person> {
  id: number;
  editNote?: string;
}
```

But I don't really want to do that, because I would need to explicitly declare a new "updater" interface for every interface I need to update.

Is there a way to make the equivalent of `<PersonUpdater>` *entirely generic*, something like

```
export interface Updater<T> = {
  id: number;
  editNote?: string;
  [prop in keyof T]?: T[prop];
};
```

to allow me to pass a generic `Updater<whatever-interface>` to my services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [intersect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) your added fields with the `Partial<>` type from the [standard library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.6.2/lib/lib.d.ts#L1317):

```
export type Updater<T> = {
  id: number;
  editNote?: string;
} & Partial<T>;
```

And then just make `PersonUpdater` as the type alias:

```
export type PersonUpdater = Updater<Person>;
```

Or as an interface if you really need to:

```
export interface PersonUpdater extends Updater<Person> {};
```

Hope that helps; good luck!